# Cannot change MFC application icon

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I'm using visual studio 2013 and I want to change the application icon in my MFC application.

I take .ico file and into `res` directory and load it to project. When I'm running, the icon isn't changed and stay MFC default icon.

Every icon that I tried to change is overridden by the MFC default icon.

How can Ichange the application icon?

Comment: replace new icon with old default mfc icon and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Take a look](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/406870/Change-ICON-of-MFC-Application-and-Dialog):

The ICON of an MFC executable is **the first ICON present in the application**.

So, we need to set our ICON as the first ICON, we can set this in `“Resource.h”`.

Open `Resource.h`, it may be like this:

[image]

Our next step is to change the ICON order as shown:

[image]

After you finish changing the application ICON, clean and rebuild your application and check your application ICON.

Comment: Hi, i did exactly like you say and the icon is still not changed :(

Comment: ok, problem solved. i forget to change on Constructor also m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDI_ICON1);, on .rc file to "ICON            IDI_ICON1, IDC_STATIC, 14, 14, 21, 20". Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Posting code as screenshots is probably the worst thing a developer could possibly think of. Plagiarizing those screenshots off the web is also pretty bad. Worse, though, you aren't even addressing the question. The question is asking, how to change the icon of the application's (main) window. Your proposed answer changes the icon, that is displayed when looking at the executable image in a file manager like Windows Explorer.

Comment: The OP clearly stated in a comment to this answer, that they **dynamically** set the application's icon (`AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDI_ICON1)`). That call is unrelated to the order of ICON resources, and is - in fact - the real solution. Your proposed answer isn't, and I voted on it to convey this. Proposing that *Resource.h* does not contain source code is very creative. And wrong.